# Saml No Cookie Preserving State ASP.NET CORE

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-core-mvc, saml, sustainsys-saml2

```
 var certbase = _env.IsDevelopment() ? "" : AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
 var pathpfx = Path.Combine(certbase, "xxxxx.pfx");
 var pathxml = Path.Combine(certbase, "metadata.xml");


.AddSaml2(options =>
                {  
                    options.SPOptions.EntityId = new EntityId("https://aaaa.aaa.com.tr");          
                    options.SPOptions.ReturnUrl = new Uri("https://localhost:5003/Account/SignInPost");
                    options.SPOptions.MinIncomingSigningAlgorithm = 
 "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1";
                    options.IdentityProviders.Add(
                    new IdentityProvider(
                    new EntityId("https://bbbbb.bbb.com.tr"), options.SPOptions)
                    {
                        MetadataLocation = pathxml,
                        LoadMetadata = true,
                        SingleSignOnServiceUrl = new Uri("https://bbbbb.bbb.com.tr/SAML/SSOService.aspx"),
                        Binding = Sustainsys.Saml2.WebSso.Saml2Binding.UriToSaml2BindingType(new 
 Uri("urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect")),
                        SingleLogoutServiceUrl = new Uri("https://bbbbb.bbb.com.tr/SAML/SLOService.aspx"),
                    });
                    options.SPOptions.ServiceCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate2(pathpfx, "password"));
                });
```

My saml was working correctly but I dont know what happened my code wasnt work now.

I got this error when i run my code on Chrome =>

**UnexpectedInResponseToException: Received message _55ae387d-0b1e-4466-9b2b-d34a5254437c contains unexpected InResponseTo "iddfcfd98961654500864ee897d823ce87". No cookie preserving state from the request was found so the message was not expected to have an InResponseTo attribute. This error typically occurs if the cookie set when doing SP-initiated sign on have been lost.**

My metadata.xml is ok
my pfx is ok as well.

**I have been looking for solving my problem more then 2 days but I couldnt find anything to help me. Whats your proposal to solve this problem? could you help me?**

inside the stack

```
UnexpectedInResponseToException: Received message _63021ef9-2b93-4b0a-ab75-88d42e8a4c9c contains unexpected InResponseTo "idc0faf551a5bf421da3a9e582b57f685a". No cookie preserving state from the request was found so the message was not expected to have an InResponseTo attribute. This error typically occurs if the cookie set when doing SP-initiated sign on have been lost.



Sustainsys.Saml2.Saml2P.Saml2Response.ValidateInResponseTo(IOptions options, IEnumerable<ClaimsIdentity> claimsIdentities)
Sustainsys.Saml2.Saml2P.Saml2Response.GetClaims(IOptions options, IDictionary<string, string> relayData)
Sustainsys.Saml2.WebSso.AcsCommand.ProcessResponse(IOptions options, Saml2Response samlResponse, StoredRequestState storedRequestState, IdentityProvider identityProvider, string relayState)
Sustainsys.Saml2.WebSso.AcsCommand.Run(HttpRequestData request, IOptions options)
Sustainsys.Saml2.AspNetCore2.Saml2Handler.HandleRequestAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: I am having a similar issue but with 4.7.2.. for me it works in firefox and IE, but not in chrome.  I'm trying to solve this currently as well.  Is yours also only an issue in chrome?

Comment: @Chris I solved the problem i will share with you . It happens because of the chrome security system.

Comment: Chris, if you cant solve you can write me. i can help you

Comment: @İbrahim What was the solution?

Answer (score 2):

You'll also get this error if your website is not secure, as I found out.

Answer (score 1):

**set this in startup.cs**

```
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.OnAppendCookie = cookieContext => SameSite.CheckSameSite(cookieContext.Context, cookieContext.CookieOptions);
            options.OnDeleteCookie = cookieContext => SameSite.CheckSameSite(cookieContext.Context, cookieContext.CookieOptions);

            //this is important. this will help you to solve the problem.
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });
```

and add this method under the public void configure(){}

```
 public static class SameSite
    {
        public static void CheckSameSite(HttpContext httpContext, CookieOptions options)
        {
            if (options.SameSite == SameSiteMode.None)
            {
                if (!BrowserSupportsSameSiteNone(httpContext.Request.Headers["User-Agent"].ToString()))
                {
                    // Unspecified - no SameSite will be included in the Set-Cookie.
                    options.SameSite = (SameSiteMode)(-1);
                }
            }
        }

        private static bool BrowserSupportsSameSiteNone(string userAgent)
        {
            // iOS 12 browsers don't support SameSite=None.
            if (userAgent.Contains("CPU iPhone OS 12") || userAgent.Contains("iPad; CPU OS 12"))
            {
                return false;
            }

            // macOS 10.14 Mojave browsers don't support SameSite=None.
            if (userAgent.Contains("Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14") && userAgent.Contains("Version/") && userAgent.Contains("Safari"))
            {
                return false;
            }

            // Old versions of Chrome don't support SameSite=None.
            if (userAgent.Contains("Chrome") || userAgent.Contains("Chrome/6"))
            {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: @İbrahim I'm having the same problem with mine, unfortunately this hasn't resolved it for me :(. Also I'll just note that the the userAgent.Contains("Chrome/6") is superflous in this case haha. Any ideas Ibrahim? I might make a seperate issue for it tomorrow.

Comment: the above solution works only, if you are running your app on https. That is what I was missing despite having above code. on my local machine it was working fine with ssl. and on remote server I didn't had ssl. So, once ssl was binded with the app. This exception was gone and Application started to work normally.